# Notification shown on receiving call not showing

Tags: android

i have added a broadcast receiver that responds to incoming call and the following is the code of the broadcast receiver onreceive method

```
Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
        if(extras!=null)
        {
            String state=extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            System.out.println(state);
            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING))
            {
                String phoneno=extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Toast.makeText(context, "proper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("no is "+phoneno);

                NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification nt=new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "You got call", System.currentTimeMillis()+2000);
                String title="You got call";
                String text="The call you got was from "+phoneno;
                Intent ii=new Intent("");
                //ii.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, ii, 0);
                nt.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, text, pi);
                nm.notify(5, nt);
                Toast.makeText(context, "proper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();





            }

        }
```

however when i send a call from the ddms ,the notification does not show.a log message if added does show in the verbose.kindly update why this is happening.
thanks
tejinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code which is working

I think that you need to write

`if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))`

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();                
       if(null == bundle)
             return;                
       Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver",bundle.toString());                
       String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);                                
       Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","State: "+ state);                
       if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
       {
               String phonenumber = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);                             
               Log.i("IncomingCallReceiver","Incomng Number: " + phonenumber);                        
               String info = "Detect Calls sample application\nIncoming number: " + phonenumber;                        
               Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```